# Export from XML

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to extract information from a XML within my table. However I am getting zero results. Can someone help please.

XML attached

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CustomRiskFormTable') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #CustomRiskFormTable;
END;

CREATE table #CustomRiskFormTable
(
    [Id]        NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    ColumnName  NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    [Value]     NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    PolicyId    INT
)

INSERT INTO #CustomRiskFormTable
SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY C.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)')) 
, C.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)')
, C.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
, pol.pol_id
FROM policies pol WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN general_insurance gen ON pol.pol_parent_id = gen.genins_id
CROSS APPLY pol.pol_interface_data.nodes('/OpportunityID/*') AS T(C)
WHERE pol.pol_id in (1952292)    

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName) 
                    FROM #CustomRiskFormTable
                    GROUP BY ColumnName, id
                    ORDER BY id
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = N'SELECT [Client Name], [Class of Risk], [Policy Description], [Policy Number], [Start Date], [Renewal Date], [Base Premium], [Invoice Total], PolicyId, ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                SELECT ent.ent_name AS ''Client Name''
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX(Value)
                FOR ColumnName IN (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '


EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

Use XML Path to grab all and then loop through

Comment: Please add a tag for the specific RDBMS you're using, as syntax and functionality varies between them. This is mentioned in the description of the SQL tag.

Comment: @Chris White can you please share sample data and let us know what you are trying to achieve.